# How can I search a rare item by name in the Auction House?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to search for existings auctions of a rare item?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66757/is-it-possible-to-search-for-existings-auctions-of-a-rare-item)

I'm fairly frustrated with searching in the auction house. I want to search for a rare item by name. Here's the only search bar I see:

[image]

As  you can see, this field is clearly marked legendary or set item. But I don't want to search for these kinds of items. I want to search for a **rare** item by name. How do I search for specific rare items in the Auction House?

And for the record, I did try to use this search field for the rare item in question. It doesn't work. It's defintiely legendary and set only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, because the names of rare items are randomly generated and meaningless. They have nothing to do with the stats of the item in question, which are generated independently of the name.

Unlike Magic Items, where the name gives you an indication of the specific stats to expect to be present, or Legendary/Set items, where, in addition to randomly generated stats, there are always several specifically assigned stats, rare items' names will not tell you anything about an item. In fact, two rares can have the *same* name, and not have a single stat in common.

Instead, search for the stats you want using the drop downs.